# Регулировка громкости MP3 файла

Tags: c#, winforms, gui

Когда настоящее время на label1 равно времени на label2 то у меня срабатывает код который включает музыку мне нужно чтобы заранее можно было регулировать громкость 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Под текстом громкость музыки я хочу ползунок громкости
Может есть какая нибудь библиотека?
Вот код с помощью которого я реализовал воспроизведение

```
   if (label1.Text == label2.Text + ":00")
            {
                WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer WMP = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
                this.Text = WMP.versionInfo;
                WMP.URL = @"D:\mokhmad\azan1.mp3 ";
                WMP.controls.play();
                button2.Visible = true;
            }
```

Главные вопросы - как сделать ползунок регулировки и как уменьшать или увеличивать с помощью него громкость

Comment: `WMP.settings.volume`

Comment: @Alexander Petrov а как сделать ползунок?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Берем, например, TrackBar в качестве ползунка.

Задаём его свойства и подписываемся на событие:

```
volumeTrackBar.Minimum = 0;
volumeTrackBar.Maximum = 100;
volumeTrackBar.ValueChanged += VolumeTrackBar_ValueChanged;
volumeTrackBar.Value = 30;
```

Обработчик события:

```
private void VolumeTrackBar_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WMP.settings.volume = volumeTrackBar.Value;
}
```

Вместо этого можно использовать привязку данных:

```
volumeTrackBar.DataBindings.Add(
    nameof(TrackBar.Value),
    WMP.settings,
    nameof(WMP.settings.volume),
    false,
    DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged
);
```

Не нравится TrackBar - можно взять HScrollBar. Код от этого не изменится.